# How do I pass a parameter to this .jsp file?

Tags: model-view-controller, java-ee-6

I want to pass a variable to ContentList.jsp.... how do I do that?  Can I add it to the dispatcher or the request?  Is the response a reference?  So if I add the parameter to the `request` object, will it already be accessible within `ContentList.jsp`?

```
public void loadView (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("ContentList.jsp");

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    System.out.println("MyServlet::LoadView() success");

    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the parameter by using

```
request.setAttribute()
```

then dispatch the request and in JSP you retrieve it with

```
request.getAtrribute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try ContentList.jsp?paramName=paramValue.